# JHipster java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, jhipster-registry

[ jsample-task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : Hikari - Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@7fd7498e marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and please share us what have you tried so far to fix the error.

Comment: I try to setup sample project, i had this error on build time.

Comment: I'm facing the same error. I tried to rum ./mvnw on root directory of the sample project and every things work. So in think this is spring tools issue